# How can I filter my R dataframe based on a column match AND ranging values?

Tags: dataframe, filter, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to filter a VCF file based on chromossome and genomic range that is present in my annotation file.

My annotation file looks like this:

| CHROM | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 64833245 | 65067732 |
| chr10 | 6010689 | 6062367 |
| chr11 | 36591943 | 36598236 |
| chr11 | 36568007 | 36579762 |

And my VCF file:

| CHROM | POS | ID | REF | ALT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| chr1 | 3 | . | A | G |
| chr10 | 6020671 | . | T | C |
| chr11 | 36591872 | . | T | G |
| chr11 | 36567002 | . | G | A |

So, I need filter my VCF based on CHROM match and variant position ranging between the annotation values "START" and "END".

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

Not on R, but the annotation file is in `.bed` format and the other file is a vcf so you can use

`bedtools --intersect`

the documentation: https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/intersect.html

the command line: `bedtools intersect  -a <FILEA> -b <FILEB>`

To sort the bedfile by chrom and by pos:
`sort -k1,1 -k2,2n in.bed > in.sorted.bed`